# Graphviz: Horizontal alignment not working with backwards arrow

Tags: graphviz, dot

I made the following graphic:

[image]

I would like to add an additional arrow, pointing back from "remote repo" all the way to "working copy" (labelled with "git pull") and I would like to have that arrow ideally first going slightly down, then left, then up.

When I simply add an arrow to the code, the graphic ends up looking like this:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
digraph G {
    /* set direction of graph to be left-->right */
    rankdir="LR";

    /* make boxes instead of ellipses */
    node [shape=box];

    /* should enforce nodes to be horizontally aligned */
    /* is not working, though... */
    rank=same;

    /* assign labels to nodes */
    wc [label="working copy"];
    id [label="index"];
    lr [label="local repo"];
    rr [label="remote repo"];

    wc -> id [label="git add"];
    id -> lr [label="git commit"];
    lr -> rr [label="git push"];

    rr -> wc [label="git pull"];
}
```

*Question*: Why is the horizontal alignment broken and how to fix this ?

*Follow-up question*: How to make an arrow pointing down, then left, then up ? (Or is the only way to do this using somehow invisible/fake nodes?)

Answer (score 5):

You may modify problematic edge with `constraint=false` attribute. Then you receive below diagram.

[image]

If you prefer much more angular edges you can also `splines=ortho` for the graph.

[image]

Please check http://graphviz.it/#/mqNwRgzu with working example. Below I've pasted source code.

```
digraph G {
    /* set direction of graph to be left-->right */
    rankdir="LR";
    splines=ortho;

    /* make boxes instead of ellipses */
    node [shape=box];

    /* should enforce nodes to be horizontally aligned */
    /* is not working, though... */
    rank=same;

    /* assign labels to nodes */
    wc [label="working copy"];
    id [label="index"];
    lr [label="local repo"];
    rr [label="remote repo"];

    wc -> id [label="git add"];
    id -> lr [label="git commit"];
    lr -> rr [label="git push"];

    rr -> wc [label="git pull", constraint=false];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it, replacing this line

```
rr -> wc [label="git pull"];
```

with

```
rr -> wc [label="git pull" weight=0];
```

[Result](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20G%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2A%20set%20direction%20of%20graph%20to%20be%20left--%3Eright%20%2A%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir%3D%22LR%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2A%20make%20boxes%20instead%20of%20ellipses%20%2A%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dbox%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2A%20should%20enforce%20nodes%20to%20be%20horizontally%20aligned%20%2A%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2A%20is%20not%20working%2C%20though...%20%2A%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2A%20assign%20labels%20to%20nodes%20%2A%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20wc%20%5Blabel%3D%22working%20copy%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%5Blabel%3D%22index%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lr%20%5Blabel%3D%22local%20repo%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rr%20%5Blabel%3D%22remote%20repo%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20wc%20-%3E%20id%20%5Blabel%3D%22git%20add%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%20-%3E%20lr%20%5Blabel%3D%22git%20commit%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lr%20-%3E%20rr%20%5Blabel%3D%22git%20push%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rr%20-%3E%20wc%20%5Blabel%3D%22git%20pull%22%20weight%3D0%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)